# Разница между между DAO и Repository

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования

Существуют ли четкие признаки разделяющие паттерны `DAO` и `Repository`, по которым можно было бы провести ясную границу между ними?

Если я правильно понял, принято считать что `Repository` это в целом более высокий уровень абстракции. Но какие существуют формальные критерии, если они есть. А если их нет, то что считать "более высоким уровнем абстракции", в контексте процедурного `SQL`, в котором как таковой вложенности объектов один в другой просто нет, а все связи реализованы при помощи внешних ключей?

Comment: через дао вы работаете с конкретной бд. репозиторий это единый интерфейс для множества моделей ( сеть, база, кеш и тд)

Comment: Эти понятия очень близки и размыты, по этому четкой границы между ними провести нельзя. [Почитайте эту статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/263033/), возможно, она вам поможет.